# Floating Div boxes limited by magic

Tags: css, html, css-float

Heres the link to the page In question....
http://team2648.com/OTIS2/DivTest.html

So If you look at that page, If your browser is small enough, you see that below the box with the red background, there is a bit of space, Why doesn't the box below float up?

[image: This is what I want.]

The HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>OTIS v1.5</title>

        <!-- Javascript - Fix the flash of unstyled content -->
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link href="css/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <!--Validation-->

        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />


        <script src="js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <!-- Meta Information -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta name="author" content="Techplex Engineer" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-10899272-10']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="header-in">
                    <h2>Online Team Information System</h2>
                    <h6>A Web Database Application for Team Profile Management</h6>
                </div> <!-- end #header-in -->
            </div> <!-- end #header -->
            <div id="content-wrap" class="clear lcol"> <!-- Navigation Column-->
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="column-in">
                        <ul>
                            <li> My </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="./"> Dashboard </a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page=manage.profile"> Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page=manage.info"> Information</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page=manage.econtact"> Emergency Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <li> Management </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="?page=manage.users"> Users </a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page=email"> Email </a></li><li><a href="?page=blog"> Blog </a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <li><a href="?page=bugs.php&referrer=/OTIS2/"> Report a Bug </a></li>
                            <li><a href="logout.php"> Logout </a></li>


                        </ul>
                        <br />
                        Logged in as:
                        <br />
                        <a href="?page=manage.profile">Blake </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="content-in">

                        <h5>Welcome to your personal dashboard Blake </h5><hr id="hr1"/>
                        <div id="bio" style="display: none;">
                            Your current Bio: <br/><textarea rows="10" cols="50"> </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div id="profilestats" class="widget">
                            <strong>IMPORTANT</strong><br/>
                            <ul style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                <li>Your Public Profile is pending moderation.</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="cal" class="widget">
                            <!--    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/team2648.com/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=200&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=team2648.com_a1ur39fpp2cn076ak2q06o8hhc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%235229A3&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style=" border-width:0 " width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>-->
                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/team2648.com/embed?showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=200&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=team2648.com_a1ur39fpp2cn076ak2q06o8hhc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%235229A3&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style=" border-width:0 " width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div id="stats" class="widget"><!-- and finally output the information formated for the widget-->
                            <strong>You have:</strong><br/>
                            <ul style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                <li>        <strong>42</strong> of 30 fundraising hours<br/></li>
                                <li>fundraised $<strong>160</strong> of $300<br/></li>
                                <li>        <strong>3</strong> of 5 community service hours<br/></li>
                                <li>        <strong>0</strong> of 40 build hours <br/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="logins" class="widget">
                            <form name="controlsForm">
                                <input id="cblogin" type="checkbox" name="loginbox"  onClick=""/> Disable Login<br />
                                <input id="cbreg" type="checkbox" name="regbox"  onClick=""/> Disable Registration<br />
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div><!-- end .content-in -->
                </div> <!-- end .content -->
            </div> <!-- end #content-wrap -->
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footer-in">
                    This system was designed, built and is maintained by Blake for Infinite Loop Robotics <br>OTIS(Online Team Information System) &copy; 2010 Techplex Labs        </div> <!-- end #footer-in -->
            </div> <!-- end #footer -->
        </div> <!-- end div#container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

You can view the css here:
http://team2648.com/OTIS2/css/styling.css

but the relevant part is this:

```
div.widget{
width: 200px;
float: left;

/*    text-align: center;*/
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 8px;
margin: 8px;

/*    margin-left:8px;
font-weight:400;*/
-moz-border-radius:11px;
-khtml-border-radius:11px;
-webkit-border-radius:11px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#fff;
border:2px solid #e5e5e5;
-moz-box-shadow:rgba(200,200,200,1) 0 4px 18px;
-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(200,200,200,1) 0 4px 18px;
-khtml-box-shadow:rgba(200,200,200,1) 0 4px 18px;
box-shadow:rgba(200,200,200,1) 0 4px 18px;
/*    padding:16px 16px 40px;*/
}
div#disclaimer
{
margin-top: 10px;
border: 1px dotted black;
font-size:10px;
background-color: #D7D7D7;
}
div.clear
{
clear: both;
}
div#profilestats
{
border:2px solid #FF9999;
}
div#cal
{
width: 400px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for magicoverflow.com

Comment: it might be that I am blind but I see to "box with red background" on the linked page.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid URL.

Comment: @mark, Yea there is that box, but below it there is a bunch of white space, I want the box below to float up into that white space.

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: Sorry, poor attempt at humour.
@mark: The box in question has a red outline and then a ton of whitespace below and then another box with a greyish outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have this as you like, but with the comments, I see when you make the full window smaller, the box with the calendar in it (cal) moves below the red Important box (profilestats).

IF you wish this to be closer (close the gap between these) what is causing the space is the DIV.widget in styling.css, margin:8px; besides that, I see nothing causing space at this point with that change - I tested this in IE8 and removing that CSS element setting did indeed push them directly conjunctual with no space between.

Now if what you mean is moving the "stats" up directly below the "profilestats" then that is another matter which can be resolved a couple of different ways.

1. put "profilestats" and "stats" in a div together (with "cal" and "logins" in
   another div together, and float both "container" divs left.
2. Use the float:left and float: right on the left and right
   elements, but that will introduce a space between if the width is
   extended (browser width) unless addressed through additional css.

In this case, I would opt for #1 as the css is easier to control.

NOTE: be cautious of margins on IE6 in float left elements at times it can be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happening is because both `profilestats` div and `cal` div are `float:left`. Try a `float:right;` on `cal` div so that the next div which is floated left(`stats`) can take the available space below `profilestats`.